# Database design tips - complex hierarchy

Tags: mysql, database

I have some issues regarding the database design of a complex hierarchy in a MySQL database. I will do my best to explain the structure as simple as possible.

I have a  large number of related objects of ~100 different types in one table. These objects are part of a hierarchy with various relations between each other. These hierarchical relations are stored in a separate table.

### Table 1

Object A

### Hierarchy table

Object A -> Object A parent(s)

### Table 2

Object B -> Object A

So far, so good. Now the problems begin. I have a number of other objects / tables which are linked to these objects (Table 2 above). At first I thought it would be easier for my queries to store three selected "main types" in these tables since this would be the most common query in the system.

This strategy will work fine most of the time but the problem is that the connection between Table 2 and Table 1 can be made on any level and any type from Table 1 which makes it a bit difficult. If I get rid of my duplicated data I will have quite impossible queries if I want to optimize the system.

How would you design this structure?

The solution I'm leaning towards right now is to either store a "main parent" for Table 1 or perhaps even json data holding the main hierarchy which can be made automatically in the system. No solution I can come up with seem good though.

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at Bill Karwins [closure tables](http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how that would apply to my case? The problem is that one object can have multiple parents and multiple children of various types.

Comment: But the typical problems are the same: query all children, grandchildren, ... query the parents, the siblings, ... The basic problem is that MySQL hasn't got support for recursion. Maybe you could adapt some ideas how to realize your concept.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I will look into it. I might have 10 or so semi-parallell trees which means 100 000 rows could very well generate millions of closure rows but I guess it will still be more efficient than trying more straight-forward hierarchical queries in MySQL. If performance becomes an issue I think there are ways to scale the closure solution.